# How to raise up a Rsync environment on WSL to mirror changes from PC to VPS?

Tags: server, ssh, backup, rsync, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have an Ubuntu 16.04.2 DigitalOcean VPS to which I usually SSH with Putty and make changes in there, but I recently found out I can make a duplicate of this server in my PC (Win10 home with WSL), do the changes here locally, and then mirror them (while SSH tunneled) via a program called `rsync`, if everything went good. The main benefit here is a comfortable, primary layer of backup.

If it is possible to use rsync in the WSL beta, how is it done from the moment `rsync` is installed, for example, if I raise up a server environment at my Win10 home WSL with this code:

```
apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install tree zip unzip make php-zip php-curl php-xml php-gd
apt-get install fail2ban
apt-get install lamp-server^ -y
a2enmod rewrite
sed -i 's/post_max_size \= .M/post_max_size \= 200M/g' /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini # regex dot instead of 2 or 8.
sed -i 's/upload_max_filesize \= .M/upload_max_filesize \= 200M/g' /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

cat <<-'LAMPENV' >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
LAMPENV

systemctl restart apache2.service
```

and I then bring up the websites on my PC locally with `localhost/site_name`, how do I mirror it with `rsync` to the VPS?

I ask this question mainly to see if what I described so far is enough - if I don't miss anything.

In an answer, please review the way I described above as a basis for the `rsync` action and say if something missing, and detail how you would do so with `rsync` in WSL afterwards.

Comment: So the question is: How do I use `rsync` over `ssh`??

Comment: And probably: How do I make a cronjob (on the host machine) that handle **r**synced files with root privileges and copy them somewhere under `/var/www`? :)

Comment: The first one but I'm not sure about the second because I really don't want to use a CronJob in the remote server if I can. Is there any chance not to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you are able to connect over SSH from the remote machine to the local one. For this purpose you must copy your private key in the directory `/root/.ssh` and it has enough restrictions - `sudo chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa`. Also you can create `/root/.ssh/config` file as this:

```
$ sudo cat /root/.ssh/config

Host my-localhost-name
    HostName 77.71.11.10
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    User my-user-name
    Port 22122
```

Now you can use `rsync` from the remote machine in this way:

```
sudo rsync -avzp -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress my-localhost-name:/var/www/<my-folder>/ /var/www/<my-folder>/
```

In case you don't have `/root/.ssh/config` file the command should be:

```
sudo rsync -avzp -e "ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -p 22122 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress my-user-name@77.71.11.10:/var/www/<my-folder>/ /var/www/<my-folder>/
```

Where:

- `-a`, `--archive` is a quick way of saying you want recursion and want to preserve almost everything  (with  -H being  a  notable  omission). The only exception to the above equivalence is when --files-from is specified, in which case -r is not implied.
- `-v`, `--verbose` increases  the amount of information you are given during the transfer.  By default, rsync works silently.
- `-z`, `--compress` - compress file data during the transfer.
- `-p`, `--perms` causes the receiving rsync to  set  the  destination permissions to be the same as the source permissions.  (See also the --chmod option for a way to modify what rsync  considers  to be the source permissions.)
- `-e`, `--rsh=COMMAND` allows you to choose  an  alternative  remote  shell program  to  use  for communication between the local and remote copies of rsync...

  Also you can add here additional options to the `ssh` command. The options used in the above example `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` are useful to keep Rsync quiet and not prompting everytime you connect to a new server.
- `--progress` show progress during transfer.

> A  trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid
>   creating an additional directory level at the destination.  You can
>   think  of a trailing `/` on a source as meaning "copy the contents of
>   this directory" as opposed to "copy the directory by  name",  but  in 
>   both  cases  the attributes   of   the  containing  directory  are 
>   transferred  to  the containing directory on the destination.  In
>   other words, each  of  the following  commands  copies  the files in
>   the same way, including their setting of the attributes of
>   `/dest/foo`:
>
> ```
> rsync -av /src/foo /dest
> rsync -av /src/foo/ /dest/foo
> ```

Sources:

- [`man rsync`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/rsync.1.html)
- [Ubuntu Documentation: SSH/OpenSSH/Keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)
- [How To Copy Files With Rsync Over SSH](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-copy-files-with-rsync-over-ssh)