# While loop only processes the first entry of ssh command

Tags: bash, ssh

So I don't know much about bash and need some pro help.
I am trying to run a script like this one:

```
filename='file1'
while read p; do
ssh -p 2222 $p 'who -b' | awk '{print $(NF-1)" "$NF}' >> file2*
```

what I am trying to make is a script that go through all addresses in file1 to see when they last rebooted and then but the answer in file2.

The problem is that it only go through the first address and not the other.

The first address got a password I need to type to proceed the process. May this be the problem or do I specify every line in file1 or am I doing absolutely wrong to begin with?

Comment: If this really is the whole script then it lacks the shebang: Add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line. Also, what exactly do you want `read` to read? If it's `filename` then add `done <"$filename"`.

Comment: I can noting but recommend [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I assumed that, the rest part of the script is okay. Then I followed [@dessert's comment](https://askubuntu.com/q/979442/566421#comment1573407_979442) and used [`shellcheck`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/shellcheck.1.html) that lead me to the actual issue and its solution:

> [SC2095](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2095): Add `< /dev/null` to prevent ssh from swallowing stdin.

So you have to change your script in this way:

```
ssh -p 2222 "$p" 'who -b' < /dev/null | awk '{print $(NF-1)" "$NF}' >> 'file2'
```

---

According to the [original answer](https://askubuntu.com/posts/979457/revisions) and thanks to the useful advises, provided in the comments by [@EliahKagan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979442/while-loop-only-processes-the-first-entry#comment1573468_979457) and [@rexkogitans](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979442/while-loop-only-processes-the-first-entry/979457#comment1573574_979457), the complete script could look as this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Collect the user's input, and if it`s empty set the default values
[[ -z "${1}" ]] && OUT_FILE="reboot-indication.txt" || OUT_FILE="$1"
[[ -z "${2}" ]] && IN_FILE="hosts.txt" || IN_FILE="$2"

while IFS= read -r host; do
    indication="$(ssh -n "$host" 'LANG=C who -b' | awk '{print $(NF-1)" "$NF}')"
    printf '%-14s %s\n' "$host" "$indication" >> "$OUT_FILE"
done < "$IN_FILE"
```

- `< /dev/null/` is replaced by the `-n` option of the `ssh` command. From [`man ssh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/ssh.1.html):

  ```bash
    -n   Redirects stdin from /dev/null (actually, prevents reading from stdin). 
         This must be used when ssh is run in the background... This does not work 
         if ssh needs to ask for a password or passphrase; see also the -f option.
  ```
- `IFS= read -r line` - as @StéphaneChazelas says in his [encyclopedic answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/201297) - is *the canonical way to read one line of input with the `read` builtin*.
- The key is that *`read` reads words from a (possibly backslash-continued) line, where words are `$IFS` delimited and backslash can be used to escape the delimiters (or continue lines).* So the `read` command should be tweaked to read lines.
- `IFS=` changes the *internal field separator* to the [null string](https://askubuntu.com/a/978715/566421), thus we preserve leading and trailing whitespace in the result.
- The option `-r` - **r**aw input - disables interpretation of backslash escapes and line-continuation in the read data ([*reference*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read)).
- `printf '%s %s' "$VAR1" "$VAR2"` will provide a better output format ([*reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10784823/6543935)).
- `LANG=C` will guarantee identical output of `who -b` on each server, thus the parsing of the output with `awk` will be guaranteed as well.
- Note here is assumed there is `~/.ssh/config` file and additional parameters as `-p 2222` are not needed ([*reference*](https://askubuntu.com/a/914678/566421)).

---

Call the above scrip `ssh-check.sh` (don't forget to `chmod +x`) and use it in this way:

- Use the default values of the input (*hosts.txt*) and the output (*reboot-indication.txt*) files:

  ```bash
    ./ssh-check.sh
  ```
- Set custom value for the output file; set custom value also for the  input files:

  ```bash
    ./ssh-check.sh 'my-custom.out'
    ./ssh-check.sh 'my-custom.out' 'my-custom.in'
  ```

---

*Read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/986245/566421) to see how the entire approach could be improved.*

Comment: Since you're showing a full script with various improvements, I suggest using `read -r p`--which is one of the things ShellCheck mentions--instead of `read p`. It's very rare that one actually wants `read` to interpret backslash escapes, and omitting the `-r` tends to make human readers (including the author, later) wonder if such an unusual situation is anticipated, so `read` should virtually always be passed the `-r` option. In addition, while in this case stripping leading and trailing whitespace is likely intended, you may want to mention the significance of not setting `IFS=` for `read`.

Comment: Instead of `< /dev/null` you can also use `ssh -n`. That's the same as per `man`.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to close the while-do loop. Add `done` to the end.

```
filename='file1'
while read p; do
   ssh -p 2222 $p 'who -b' | awk '{print $(NF-1)" "$NF}' >> file2*
done
```