# Moving only those files that appear in the list

Tags: command-line

I have a list of some names/IDs and in the same directory I have original files from that list. I am trying to find how I can move original files to another folder, but only those that appear into list?

So my list/txt file looks like this:

```
2mtz.pdb
2lbq.pdb
2kad.pdb
```

and my original files have exactly same ID but I have to find a way how to move only those from the list.

Answer (score 2):

If the list is in the file `/tmp/list.txt` you can do in the following way:

```
cat /tmp/list.txt | xargs mv -t /app/dest/
```

or shorter:

```
xargs mv -t /app/dest/ < /tmp/list.txt
```

Is a combination of commands:

```
mv -t /app/dest/
```

For move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY using the option  -t or --target-directory=DIRECTORY

And using the command `xargs` which execute command lines from standard input, but in this case every line on `/tmp/list.txt` because we made a redirection using the `<`

credit to this other Q&A https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115734/move-file-by-list-in-file-with-leading-whitespace

Comment: Hm, I found my answer is also provides within the link you've shared :) It could be nice to add some explanations of what actually `xargs` does. Whether the `-t` option is related to the `mv` command or it is related to `xargs`.

Comment: OK, edited to improve the answer, but all the credit is for the original Q&A.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two examples that use `while` loop.

---

In the next example, the content of the file called `list` will be redirected to the `while` loop, where each line will be `read` as value of the variable `$FILE_NAME`, that will be used as an argument in the `mv` command.

```
while IFS= read -r FILE_NAME; do mv "$FILE_NAME" "/dest/dir/"; done < /path/to/list
```

---

In the next example, the command `cat` will output the content of the file called `list`. The output will be piped to the `while` loop, where each line will be `read` as value of the variable `$FILE_NAME`, that will be used as an argument in the `mv` command.

```
cat /path/to/list | while IFS= read -r FILE_NAME; do mv "$FILE_NAME" "/dest/dir/"; done
```

---

IMO using redirection is the better way. Here is provided more detailed explanation abut this usage of `while`: [While loop only processes the first entry of ssh command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979442/while-loop-only-processes-the-first-entry-of-ssh-command/979457#979457).

Answer (score 2):

In Unix, if we try hard, filenames may have all sort of unexpected characters. Whenever possible we generally avoid using spaces, '?', '\n', '(', '*', etc in filenames and directories.

If your filenames don't have "spaces" and other strange characters, try:

```
mv $(cat list/txt) destination/dir/
```

Comment: They dont have. They are all number followed by three letter characted, but no spaces for sure!

Comment: I'd like to add that the path separator `/` isn't allowed, anyway, in filenames. This and the null byte are the only characters prohibited in Unix filenames.

Comment: @StefanHamcke, thank you for the correction. It makes sense! (I will fix it)

Comment: @StefanHamcke Yeah, that is true; whenever I run the script and the input is a file that has some of these characters It cant be read.

Comment: @milan, the command presented is only applicable to known reasonable  content! In hostile environment this is obviously  unsafe!!  (ex: filelist containing "f ; command" -- comand would be executed)