# Using ssh in cron script

Tags: 16.04, ssh, cron

I have a problem running a ssh from crontab against a Fujitsu DX200 storage appliance.

When running the command from terminal everything works okay connecting using RSA keys, but when I embed the command in a script and run it from cron it fails with "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal."

The command is `ssh user@dx200 "show performance -type host-io"`

According to many articles on the net, adding a number of `-t` as an argument to ssh it should force allocating PTY. On RedHat, where the script was developed, it works by adding `-t -t -t` (or `-ttt`) but that's not the case when running on Ubuntu.

Using ssh -T (Disable pseudo-tty allocation) makes the login to dx200 fail with "FUJITSU Storage ETERNUS login is required..." - that is, not logging in whit RSA key.

Other solutions from the net, using variants of `ssh ... /bin/bash <<EOF ...` is not possible because we cant launch a shell on the storage appliance.

Any ideas on how to circumvent this issue?

Comment: It looks like that I solved the problem. An extra `-t` on the ssh command and there are connection through. Now there are four.  What are the mechanism that decides how many `-t` are necessary ?

Comment: What about the option `-n`?  I'm thinking whether your question is possible duplicate of [While loop only processes the first entry of ssh command](https://askubuntu.com/q/979442/566421) (see also [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/986179/566421))?

Comment: @pa4080, I tried that too, it didn't work either. As I remember, it broke the login. This might be because the sshd or the shell in the DX200 is a little rudimentary compared to a linux setup.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question ...

Adding an extra `-t` argument to ssh solved the problem.

The command now looks like `ssh -t -t -t -t user@dx200 ......` ( `-tttt` should do the same).

The man page on ssh say's this about -t:

```
 -t      Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbi-
         trary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
         very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
         options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

But nothing about how many 'Multiple' is, or what in the ssh code that governs the number of `-t` options required.