# Converting numbers in a CSV file to their corresponding URLs

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

I have a CSV file with two columns (and a header) where each of its elements includes any number between 0 to 199. I want to convert these to their corresponding URLs. Here is an example:

```
41,51
```

should become:

```
http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/41.jpg,http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/51.jpg
```

Here is the list.csv file I want to convert:

```
$ head list.csv
imageA,imageB
41,51
172,100
99,149
83,72
84,160
186,8
93,198
150,21
63,102
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```bsh
sed -r 's#^([0-9]+),([0-9]+)$#http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/\1\.jpg,http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/\2\.jpg#' input-file
```

- redirect the output to a new file `> output-file`; or use the option `-i.bak` to make the changes in their places and create a backup file.
- `-r`, `--regexp-extended` - use extended regular expressions in the script.
- the command `s` means substitute: `#<string-or-regexp>#<replacement>#`.
- `#` is used as delimiter - usually `/` plays this role, but here we have much slashes within the `<replacement>`, thus we do not need to escape each of them.
- `^` will match to the beginning of the line. `$` will match to the end of the line.
- `[0-9]+` will match to each string consisting of digits.
- within the the `<replacement>`, the capture groups `([0-9]+)`, will be treated as the variables `\1` and `\2`.
- `\.` is just escape of the special meaning of the dot.

---

Here is a simplification proposed by [@dessert](https://askubuntu.com/users/507051/dessert):

```bsh
sed -r 's#([0-9]+)#http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/\1\.jpg#g' input-file
```

- here we assume the file format is homogeneous, as it is in the example, and we do not need to match the whole line.
- the `g` flag (at the end) repeats the substitution for each occurrence of the matched regex to the end of the line.

---

In addition it is possible to use also variables for the base URL and for the file extension:

```bsh
URL='http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/'; EXT='.jpg'
sed -r "s#([0-9]+)#$URL\1$EXT#g" input-file
```

- Note: here are used double quote marks.

Answer (score 6):

I'd probably use `awk` e.g.

```
awk -F, -v baseurl='http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/' '
  FNR>1 {printf("%s%d.jpg,%s%d.jpg\n", baseurl, $1, baseurl, $2)}
' list.csv
http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/0.jpg,http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/0.jpg
http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/41.jpg,http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/51.jpg
http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/172.jpg,http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/100.jpg
http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/99.jpg,http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/149.jpg
http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/83.jpg,http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/72.jpg
http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/84.jpg,http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/160.jpg
http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/186.jpg,http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/8.jpg
http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/93.jpg,http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/198.jpg
http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/150.jpg,http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/21.jpg
http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/63.jpg,http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/102.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a code for you:

```bsh
firstline=true
url_before_id=http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/
url_after_id=.jpg
for id in $(less list.csv)
do
  if $firstline;then
    firstline=false;echo $id
  else echo "$url_before_id${id%%,*}$url_after_id","$url_before_id${id##*,}$url_after_id"
  fi
done
```

or in one line

```bsh
firstline=true;url_before_id=http://www.cs.bu.edu/~betke/research/vc-crowd/MSCOCO/;url_after_id=.jpg;for id in $(less list.csv);do if $firstline;then firstline=false;echo $id;else echo "$url_before_id${id%%,*}$url_after_id","$url_before_id${id##*,}$url_after_id";fi;done
```

Comment: nominated for [The Useless Use of Cat Award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)

Comment: @dessert thank you for the nomination ;-) One never stops learning

Comment: true that. To read a file line by line you should rather use `read`, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/6164712).

Comment: You can use [`bash` Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), try `id=41,51;echo a${id/,/b,a}b`.

Comment: Here is [example](https://askubuntu.com/a/979457/566421) how to use `read` with `while` loop instead of `for`:: `while IFS= read -r id; do echo "$id"; done < input-file`