# How to write in bash to ssh to different machine and create tmux session then run some command in it

Tags: bash, ssh, tmux

Basically I want to write some script like

```
#!/bin/bash
for idx in 1 2 3 4 5 6
do
        ssh machine$idx tmux new-session -d -s "myTempSession$idx" python run.py
done
```

which can do the thing separately on each machine as:

```
ssh machine$idx 

tmux new-session -d -s "myTempSession$idx"

python run.py
```

but after many trial and error, I still cannot make it work as expected.

Comment: Works fine for me. You might want to share a bit more detail of what goes wrong. Remember the classical problem report schema: action - expected result - actual result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should divide the two actions 1) create a `tmux` detached session; 2) send a command/keys to it. Also maybe adding the [`-n` option](https://askubuntu.com/a/979457/566421) is a good idea... So your script should look like as:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for idx in 1 2 3 4 5 6
do
    ssh -n machine$idx 'tmux new-session -d -s "myTempSession$idx"; tmux send-keys -t "myTempSession$idx" "python run.py" ENTER'
done
```