# How to transfer a file from my Ubuntu Server in VirtualBox to my local Ubuntu machine?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, virtualbox

I am trying to transfer a file from my Ubuntu Server 18.04 installed in VirtualBox to my local machine, but I can't get it work.

The network in place is NAT, in VirtualBox I have set port forwarding.

```
*Name*      *Protocol*  *Host IP*   *Host port*     *Guest IP*   *Guest port*
ssh           TCP                    2222                           22
```

To connect to my server I'm using `ssh xander@127.0.0.1 -p 2222`. 
However I'm not able to transfer a file from the VirtualBox instance to my local machine.

`scp user@remotehost:/file/to/copy /local/destination` doesn't work I have tried several times.

I have tried following this [stackoverflow guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903038/how-to-copy-or-move-files-from-remote-machine-to-local-machine) for NAT firewall based machines but whenever I ran this command with my credentials `ssh ComputerBUser@ComputerB -R 2222:localhost:22` I get `Bad port '2222:localhost:22'` so I cant do much.

Comment: Did you install openssh-server? If you did not install openssh-server on the "remote" host then you will not be able to use ssh, scp, sftp, or rsync to it because they all use ssh.

Comment: yes openssh-server is installed..i have tried using scp no avail

Answer (score 0):

> To connect to my server I'm using `ssh xander@127.0.0.1 -p 2222`

Within SCP the port must be provided too - note here the port option is capital `-P`, and this option must be placed at the beginning of the command:

```
scp -P 2222 xander@127.0.0.1:/file/to/copy /local/destination/
```

IMO, for such tasks `rsync` is better, faster and robust ([more explanations](https://www.tecmint.com/sync-files-using-rsync-with-non-standard-ssh-port/)):

```
rsync -e 'ssh -p 2222' --progress user@remotehost:/file/to/copy /local/destination/
```

---

At all, I would prefer setup bridged connection for the virtual machine, thus it will have its own IP address in my local network

---

In addition I would advice you to setup ssh key based authentication and `.ssh/config` file - here is a short list with references about this:

- [Filezilla or WinSCP alternative for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/987769/566421)
- [How to raise up a Rsync environment on WSL to mirror changes from PC to VPS?](https://askubuntu.com/q/914551/566421)
- [Permission denied when trying to run a script that uses 'sshpass'](https://askubuntu.com/q/986179/566421)

Comment: when i run `xander@ariella:~$scp xander@ariella:stunnel.pem ~/Desktop -P 2222` i get 
*2222: No such file or directory*

Comment: Hi, @xaander1, this is my fault, the option must be at the beginning of the command - see the updated answer.

Comment: now am getting *ssh: connect to host ariella port 2222: Connection refused*

Comment: @xaander1, I've updated the answer once again :)

Comment: still giving `ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 2222: Connection refused` have you tried it practically.

Comment: Of course, I have, @xaander1 :) The difference is I'm using VM with bridged connection that gets its IP from my routers DHCP...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100212/discussion-between-xaander1-and-pa4080).